# Grails App Deployed as ROOT.war, j_spring_security_check throwing NPE and HTTP 500

Tags: grails, spring-security, tomcat6

Grails 1.3.6
Tomcat6

I created a production ROOT.war.  Deleted the default tomcat ROOT directory.  Deployed the ROOT.war and started tomcat.  The app kicks off just fine.  However, it seems like the spring security filter isn't processing correctly.  For starters, I can access protected pages but errors are thrown because of not being able to access the logged in principal.  Another issue if that after I submit login creds, the server is returning an NPE and HTTP status code of 500 on http://host:8080/j_spring_security_check.

I should note that locally I have app.context=/ in application.properties and everything locally works just fine at http://localhost:8080/

Anyone have any ideas here?

UPDATE: For whatever reason, this time around I got more of a stacktrace for the NPE so I am posting it here

```
java.lang.NullPointerException

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.equalsIgnoreCase(ByteChunk.java:563)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.MessageBytes.equalsIgnoreCase(MessageBytes.java:335)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getValue(MimeHeaders.java:289)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.getHeader(MimeHeaders.java:318)

    at org.apache.coyote.Request.getHeader(Request.java:330)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getHeader(Request.java:1877)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getHeader(RequestFacade.java:643)

    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeader(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:80)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils.isAjax(SpringSecurityUtils.java:299)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.determineTargetUrl(AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:42)

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.handle(AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.java:67)

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:42)

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:63)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(AjaxAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler.java:65)

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:301)

    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:40)

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:79)

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)

    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)

    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:167)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:69)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:65)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)

    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)

    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)

    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)

    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the application's doing a `request.getHeader(ajaxHeaderName)`, where name is:

```
String ajaxHeaderName = (String)ReflectionUtils.getConfigProperty("ajaxHeader");
```

(See `isAjax()` at line 294 [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/springsecurity/SpringSecurityUtils.java))

The default value for `ajaxHeader` is `'X-Requested-With'` ([here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/grails-app/conf/DefaultSecurityConfig.groovy)).

Are you explicitly setting the configuration value to something different in prod?

This isn't a very definitive answer, but maybe it'll send you down the right debugging path.

Comment: No, I'm not setting anything explicitly on prod with regards to anything Ajax.  And there is no ajax happening when this issue comes up.  But thanks for the investigation.  I'll keep digging.

Comment: There is no real answer to this question because the issue is so unrelated to the cause.  So I'm marking this answer as correct as a thanks for attempting to help.

Comment: @Gregg - Glad you figured it out. I won't feel bad if you accept your own answer, given that mine was just a stab in the dark.

Comment: that's ok.  I'm still not 100% sure what the exact cause is so even my own answer is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so long story short, it didn't have anything to do directly with Spring Security.  I'm still piecing it all together but it has something to do with a combination of plugins we're maintaining (more like project modules), inline plugin config, plugin dependency, and production war.